# How to get dynamic value on progress bar using jquery and Laravel

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, laravel, datatable

I have Data Table with two columns Emp Features and Correlation, in correlation column I want to show the progress bar with values coming from database. I have Column called SHAP_abs in database whose value should be shown in progress bar. Also the datatype for SHAP_abs is varchar.
Here is my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
  $(document).ready(function(SHAP_abs){  
   var progressBarVal= SHAP_abs*100;
   alert(progressBarVal);    
   var html="<div class='progress-bar progress-bar-striped active' role='progressbar' aria-valuenow="+progressBarVal+" aria-valuemin='0' aria-valuemax='100' style='width:"+progressBarVal+"%'>"+progressBarVal+"%</div>";    
   $(".progress").append(html);    
  });    
  </script>
```

This is how my HTML looks like:

```
@foreach($Correlations_list as $corr)
                @if($corr->Variable == $row )
                  <td class="col-md-4">
                    
                   <div class="progress">    
                   
                  </td> 
                @endif
              @endforeach
```

And this is my Controller:

```
public function show(Prediction $detail)
    
        {
            
            
            $Correlations_list=Correlation::all();
            return view('admin.members.Detailspage',compact('detail','Correlations_list'));
            
        }
```

Correlation in my table name. Can someone suggest what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you get any error in console ?

Comment: Yes...it says undefined

Comment: @MayankPandeyz  Yes...it says undefined if I add row to function, and if i use same as above code it says NaN

Comment: @MayankPandeyz  `@foreach($Correlations_list as $corr)` `$corr->SHAP_abs` ...Can I use something like this to get SHAP_abs in script?

Comment: @MayankPandeyz Correlations in my Table name and SHAP_abs is column name...I think I am directly calling Column without running loop is this reason ?